# IP Configuration Google Cloud VPS and CPanel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cpanel, google-cloud-networking

I created a vps instance on the google cloud platform that is configured with an internal network interface and assigned to it there is an external im.

I configured the nameserver in vps with my domain and in cpanel it assigns this external ip to the nameserver through the page [Server Configuration] Basic WebHost ManagerSetup]. In this page I configured two nameservers with the same IP [ns1.domain and ns2.domain].

In the service of registration of domains of Brazil [registration.br] I can not register the nameservers for appointment of my domain with the same IP. So I need to set up two ips for pointing in my vps and I do not know which feature does this process.

After this process create a new vps instance in google cloud, I configured this new instance with two network interfaces, but when trying to ping I can only perform for the primary ip and the secondary ip can not be found. Where and what configuration should I perform so that my server can have two ips (primary and secondary) and I can properly set up the notes in the domain registry?

My need is to have a VPS server with cpanel installed where I can have several hosted sites / services, each with its own domain and each being created / managed by an independent cpanel account.

The notes I need to have is where my primary domain has the pointing configuration for the server and all the accounts hosted on vps have their pointing done for my primary domain. (maindomain points to my hosted server and domain pointing to my primary domain).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try the troubleshooting steps in the official [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces). You would have to setup a default route on that secondary network interface.

1. Verify if firewall rules allow access to the second interface.
2. Verify if you are trying to connect to the second NIC from an
   Internet address or from outside of the secondary interface's
   network.
3. Verify if you are trying to establish a connection to the
   secondary NIC from outside the subnet the secondary interface is
   attached to.